# R odbc::odbcListDrivers() does not list dirver in /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, unixodbc

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database from R studio.

I installed the unixODBC driver manager using homebrew:

```
brew install unixodbc
```

I then tried to install the freetds driver as recommended on https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/drivers/

```
# SQL Server ODBC Drivers (Free TDS)
  brew install freetds --with-unixodbc
```

I received the error:

```
Error: invalid option: --with-unixodbc
```

I found a source saying the option is no longer available because it is default now. Thus, I ran:

```
brew install freetds
```

In R Studio (and R) I then attempted to list the installed driver, but it was not found:

```
> odbc::odbcListDrivers()
[1] name      attribute value    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Next I tried to install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (macOS) according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15 and as recommended on https://db.rstudio.com/databases/microsoft-sql-server/

I ran:

```
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1 ACCEPT_EULA=Y brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

To check that this driver was registered in an odbcinst.ini file I first ran:

```
odbcinst -j
```

with result:

```
unixODBC 2.3.9
DRIVERS............: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /opt/homebrew/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/Gina/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

The driver was already registered in /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
view /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini
```

file contents (note the freetds driver does not appear to be present):

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

In Rstudio, I tried again to list the drivers and none were found:

```
> odbc::odbcListDrivers()
[1] name      attribute value    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I have tried many more things, including:

1. copying the contents of /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini to the user level file /Users/Gina/.odbcinst.ini
2. editing the /opt/homebrew/etc/odbc.ini file (which was previously empty) to include connection details (though I was planning to just specify these in the DBI::dbConnect command). New redacted file contents:

   ```
    [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
    Driver   = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
    Servername   = servername.net
    Database = databasename
    UserName     = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user")
    Password      = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")
    Port     = 1433
   ```
3. copying the contents of the /opt/homebrew/etc/odbc.ini to the user level file /Gina/.odbc.ini
4. setting an environmental variable:

   ```
    export ODBCSYSINI=/opt/homebrew/etc
   ```

Note that when I run:

```
odbcinst -q -s
```

The driver is found:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
```

Thus, it appears that odbc::odbcListDrivers() should be able to find the driver. Any thoughts or suggestions would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT:
I also tried using the New Connection button and interestingly, my driver is listed there!
[New Connection Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rr1e.png)

However, when I click on it and click Test, I get an error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

[Driver Connection Window with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw6nO.png)

I get the same error when I try:

```
isql -v ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server myusername mypassword
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no     
default driver specified
```

EDIT 2:
I changed the Data Source Name (top line in odbc.ini file) to "SQLSever" and changed the Servername argument to Server (I did this in both the system level file and the user level file). Now when I run the below command it tries to connect (though hits a new error).

```
isql -v SQLServer myusername mypassword

[08001][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL   
Provider: [OpenSSL library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL   
1.0 or 1.1 is installed]
[08001][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client    
unable to establish connection
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

However, unfortunately, I still can not connect in R. I get the same errors as before.

Note that it appears that the isql command uses the system level files and RStudio uses the user level files. The files are identical in both places.

Comment: I've never seen `odbcinst.ini` files that could include R code for dynamic determination (e.g., user and pass); I *have* seen that `config.yml` files (via the `config::` package) *can* do this via something like `db:\n  uid: !expr rstudioapi::askForPassword("User")\n`. Is it listed somewhere that that method is supported?

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the comment! I am not sure that it is supported. These were copied from the dbConnect command I was planning to use within R. To test whether this was the cause of my problem, I changed them to the actual username and password and I stil can not list the drivers from within R Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With M1 Mac I was able to connect to SQL Server through terminal by changing the openssl folder to an older version. The driver installs openssl@3 (opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3) but you actually need to use openssl@1.1 instead.

Here are the steps i followed in terminal:

```
brew install openssl@1.1
rm /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl
ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1l_1 /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl
```

This will create a symlink "openssl" and point it to the correct file (1.1.1l_1) inside the opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1 folder.
Before creating the symlink verify the file name 1.1.1l_1 has not changed with a newer version in opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1l_1

Answer (score 2):

I read in a post on a similar issue that the M1 Macs have this problem but non-M1 Macs do not. Thus, I tried repeating the whole process on an older Macbook Pro and did not encounter the problem! odbc::odbcListDrivers() immediately listed the driver after installing the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (macOS). I did not need to edit or create any files.

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/474) worked for me:

Create two symlinks:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/etc
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/etc/odbc.ini /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

For [MSSQL driver install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15) on Intel Mac (Ventura) and R 4.3.1, I created the symlinks mentioned under [Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15#troubleshooting), but `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` still returned an empty table.

**My solution:**

1. Find installed paths.
   Run `odbcinst -j` to list the paths for installed drivers:

> ```
> <username@machine> % odbcinst -j
> unixODBC 2.3.12
> DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
> SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
> FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
> USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/<username>/.odbc.ini
> SQLULEN Size.......: 8
> SQLLEN Size........: 8
> SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
> ```

2. Override R's ODBC Driver Path:
   Following the [POSIT Instructions for MacOS aarch64](https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/best-practices/drivers/?_gl=1*10rwzxh*_ga*OTExMjE4MzQ0LjE2ODA4NzA4NjM.*_ga_2C0WZ1JHG0*MTY4MDk2MDI1NS4yLjEuMTY4MDk2MDMxMS4wLjAuMA..#macos-aarch64) I edited my .Renviron file (`nano /Users/<username>/.Renviron`) to add the line: `ODBCSYSINI=/etc` I know that the `/etc` folder contains a symlink to `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini` because I created the symlink following the Troubleshooting steps in the original article.
3. Restart RStudio.
   Now `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` lists the same drivers as are found in `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini`.

Just sub in your DRIVER path (`/opt/homebrew/etc/`) instead of mine, and your symlink path: `ODBCSYSINI=/opt/homebrew/etc/`) and I suspect it should work without having to copy any files.

Comment: this works on Apple Silicon Mac as well.